# Using Bootstrap with Ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I use Bootstrap in Ember.js

Is there any best practice somewhere? I know I can just use the styles / javascript behaviors of Bootstrap as is but it lacks communication with my application controllers,

Thanks

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">` ... goes in head of index.html

Answer (score 14):

Yes,

Try: https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

It is a set of Ember components styled with Bootstrap v3,

There's also a showcase available here:

http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember

Few components already available such as: Modal Pane, Alerts, ProgressBar, Pills, Tab, Etc, Navigations, etc.

There are more special components that don't exist in Bootstrap such as Notifications:
http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/#/show_components/notifications

Goodluck.

Comment: That components library is great but I'd also like to have Bootstrap's grid.  For that I usually just include the css library.  bootstrap-for-ember seems to have neglected that, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The above mentioned is deprecated now. The replacement indexiatech has a larger scope than bootstrap JS.

Answer (score 1):

[You can try ember-bootstrap](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/)

Install using

```
ember install ember-bootstrap
```

and add

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-bootstrap': {
        'importBootstrapCSS': true,
        'importBootstrapFont': true
    }
});
```

to your *ember-cli-build.js* and your good to go.